# Getting JSON data with jquery ajax not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to understand how to fetch and display data with jquery ajax. I have a php page `(data.php)`that successfully retrieves data from a mysql database and encodes that data into a json array. Client side I have a page called `get.php`. I just can't figure out why my script will not fetch any data from `data.php` I get nothing in the firebug console.

**data.php**

```
echo json_encode($mydata);
```

which outputs:

```
[  
   {  
      "id":"236",
      "title":"The Jungle Book"
   },
   {  
      "id":"235",
      "title":"The Shallows"
   },
   {  
      "id":"232",
      "title":"For Your Eyes Only"
   },
   {  
      "id":"231",
      "title":"Ice Giants"
   }
]
```

**get.php**

```
<script>
    ("button").click(function(){
      {
        $.ajax({                                      
          url: 'data.php',                       
          data: "",                       
          dataType: 'json',                    
          success: function(data)          
          {
            var id = data[0];             
            var title = data[1];           
            
            $('#output').html("<b>id: </b>"+id+"<b> name: </b>"+vname);
          } 
        });
      }); 
</script>

    <h3>Output: </h3>
    <button>Get Data</button>
    
      <div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: You're missing the `$` before `("button")` and extra `{`.

Comment: Is this the actual order in the markup (script before button)? If so, then you will have to wrap the code in a [`ready` handler](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) or move the complete `<script>` at the bottom of the page, right before the closing `</body>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You have few mistake like: you didn't specify `jquery($)` for button
>   selector, you use multiple bracket `{` inside click function, inside
>   ajax success you have assigned full object against `id` and `title` it
>   should be `id=data[0]['id']` and `title=data[0]['title]` and another
>   mistake there no defined variable `vname`. php better json output you should use `header('Content-Type: application/json');` in `data.php`.

Try this: 
 **index.php**

```
<h3>Output: </h3>
<button>Get Data</button>
<div id="output"></div>
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"   integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({                                      
          url: 'data.php',                       
          data: "",                       
          dataType: 'json',                    
          success: function(data){
            //console.log(data);
            var id = data[0].id;             
            var title = data[1].title;           
            $('#output').html("<b>id: </b>"+id+"<b> name: </b>"+title);
          } 
        });
      }); 
</script>
```

**data.php**

```
<?php 
 header('Content-Type: application/json'); //use header to specify data type
 //echo json_encode($mydata); // un-comment this line
 echo '[{"id":"236", "title":"The Jungle Book"}, {"id":"235", "title":"The Shallows"}, {"id":"232", "title":"For Your Eyes Only"}, {"id":"231", "title":"Ice Giants"} ]'; // comment this line
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
$("button").click(function()
  {
    $.ajax({                                      
      url: 'data.php',                       
      data: "",                       
      dataType: 'json',                    
      success: function(data)          
      {
        var id = data[0];             
        var title = data[1];           
        $('#output').html("<b>id: </b>"+id+"<b> name: </b>"+vname);
      } 
    });
   });
```

try like this